# How to build and link libpng for Windows

Tags: c++, libpng

I am trying to build and link libpng so that I can I use it with Eclipse, C++, and Windows 8.1 (64 bit).

I'm using the GCC C++ compiler with options:

> -I"C:\zlib-1.2.8" -I"C:\lpng1625" -I"C:\CImg\CImg-1.7.5" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0  -Dcimg_use_png -lpng16 -v

And the MinGW C++ linker with options:

> -L"C:\lpng1625" -L"C:\zlib-1.2.8"
>   and libraries are set to: gdi32, z, and png1625.

I've also tried variants of png16, png15, and png15.

My error message is: "Cannot find -lpng1625"

Do I need to build libpng?  If so, how can I do this?

Comment: It's just `-lpng`

Comment: Ok.  Now I get "cannot find -lpng".  I think I need to build it, but am unsure how to create a makefile (and how to use a makefile).

Comment: I'm going to try using win-builds.

Comment: Using win-builds and their dll, I get an error: 
g++ "-LC:\\zlib-1.2.8" "-LC:\\win-builds\\bin" -o TileMap.exe "src\\TileMap.o" -lgdi32 -lz -lpng 
C:\win-builds\bin/libpng.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized

Comment: Maybe I should be using c:\win-builds\lib64 instead? With that I get a 1000+ errors like:

Description Resource Path Location Type
undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception' TileMap  line 10097, external location: C:\CImg\CImg-1.7.5\CImg.h C/C++ Problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work by using Visual Studio 15 and the NuGet package manager.

NuGet made it very easy to install libpng (and automatically installed its dependencies including zlib).  Next I included Cimg.h by adding its directory under the project properties and "Include Directories". Finally I had to install GraphicsMagick so that CImg could save PNG files. I did this by downloading the windows binary.